# Can nodejs redis error occur because of crawler?

Tags: redis, nestjs

redis v 4.0.6 is in use.

Is there an error if the crawler connects repeatedly?

My code is as follows,

```
  private setRedisClient() {
        const client = createClient({
            url: `redis://${process.env.REDIS_URL}:${process.env.REDIS_PORT}`,
            isolationPoolOptions: {
                max: 10,
                min: 0,
                maxWaitingClients: 10,
                fifo: true,
                autostart: true,
                idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
            },
        });

        client.on('error', (e: any) => {
            throw e;
        });

        return client;
    }

  try {
            this.setRedisClient();
            await this.client.connect();
            const res = await this.client.hGetAll(key);
            await this.client.quit();
            return res;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return undefined;
        }
```

Repeated refreshing of a page results in an error.

```
ClientClosedError: The client is closed
    at RedisSocket.quit (/home/ec2-user/buyer-service/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/socket.js:72:19)
    at Commander.QUIT (/home/ec2-user/buyer-service/node_modules/@redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:222:71)
    at RedisClient.getAll (/home/ec2-user/buyer-service/dist/infra/cache/redis/cache.redis.client.js:31:31)
```

I am not good at speaking English.

I ask for your help me.

Comment: Without seeing what `this.setRedisClient()` does and without knowing what client library and version you are using, I'm not sure I can offer much. Could you provide that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async getAll(key: string): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const client = this.setRedisClient();
            const [_, hGetAll, _a] = await Promise.all([client.connect(), client.hGetAll(key), client.quit()]);
            return hGetAll;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return undefined;
        }
    }
```